# Error "expecting array" with PHP array_flip() function

Tags: php, array-flip

I recently updated the server on which I work. I have got an error:

> "Warning: array_flip() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in..."

Does someone know how to fix it?

Here is a part of PHP code:

```
function redirectWrongDep($url) { 
    $deps = @getDepsByIdUrl($url); 
    $depsFlip = array_flip($deps); 
    if ($_GET['dep'] && !in_array($_GET['dep'], $depsFlip)) { header('Location:'.URL); 
        exit(); 
    } 
} 
function getDepsByIdUrl($url) { 
    $sql = "SELECT ws_flash_departement.nom,ws_flash_departement.id_departement FROM ws_flash_departement WHERE ws_flash_departement.no_resultats != 0 AND ws_flash_departement.id_departement IN (SELECT url_departement.id_departement FROM url_departement WHERE url_departement.id_url=" . $url . ") ORDER BY nom ASC"; 
    $result = mysql_query($sql); 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        $deps[$row["id_departement"]]=utf8_encode($row["nom"]); 
    } 
    mysql_free_result($result); 
    return $deps; 
 }
```

Comment: You are trying to flip a NULL

Answer (score 1):

most likely you updated to an server where magic quotes is set on off

This id because something is returning the value `false` or  not returning `true` or `1` so debug the code .you are not suplling anything too the `array_flip()` you have to supply `array`

example:

```
$arr = array("a" => 3, "b" => 1, "c" => 2);
$arr = array_flip($arr);
print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

array_flip takes an array as first parameter and you give nothing...

PS: Maybe with some lines of code, I could give you a more precise answer

Comment: Here is a part of PHP code :

function redirectWrongDep($url) {
    $deps = @getDepsByIdUrl($url);
    $depsFlip = array_flip($deps);
    if ($_GET['dep'] && !in_array($_GET['dep'], $depsFlip)) {
        header('Location:'.URL);
        exit();
    }
}

Comment: A second part :

function getDepsByIdUrl($url) {
$sql = "SELECT ws_flash_departement.nom,ws_flash_departement.id_departement FROM ws_flash_departement WHERE ws_flash_departement.no_resultats != 0 AND 
                            ws_flash_departement.id_departement IN (SELECT url_departement.id_departement FROM url_departement WHERE url_departement.id_url=" . $url . ") ORDER BY nom ASC";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $deps[$row["id_departement"]]=utf8_encode($row["nom"]);
    }
    mysql_free_result($result);
    return $deps;
}

Comment: What's the value returned by getDepsByIdUrl ?

Comment: This function returns an array of departments (it is a french project).
The french Departments are from 1 to 95.

Comment: I mean does it return what you are expecting ? Did you print_r this array ?

Answer (score 0):

Check this manual:

`http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php`

Eg.

```
$trans = array("a" => 1, "b" => 1, "c" => 2);
$trans = array_flip($trans);
print_r($trans);
```